# how to configure dhcp?

Tags: 12.10, internet, dhcp

I have still problems with internet connection on my network using Ubuntu 12.10. I have router NetGear 192.168.1.1, then TP-Link running on his 192.168.1.2 and Ubuntu connected through wire to TP-Link with 192.168.0.200. It runs OK, but sometimes IP is not renewed and I loose internet. I am coming over it by plug out and in wire up to the point that I have 192.168.1.3 or 192.168.0.200 IP and then `kill-9` and restarting `dhcpcd eth0` . I cant figure out from where goes this 192.168.1.3 address which I think is source of my problems.
I see this in my dhcp liases file:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.3;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
  option domain-name "chello.pl";
  renew 4 2013/04/25 09:52:47;
  rebind 4 2013/04/25 20:26:26;
  expire 4 2013/04/25 23:26:26;
}
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.0.200;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 7200;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;
  renew 4 2013/04/25 21:17:52;
  rebind 4 2013/04/25 22:11:32;
  expire 4 2013/04/25 22:26:32;
}
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.3;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option domain-name "chello.pl";
  renew 5 2013/04/26 07:27:14;
  rebind 5 2013/04/26 17:28:47;
  expire 5 2013/04/26 20:28:47;
}
```

what even more strange to me: ifconfig says I am running my desirable 192.160.0.200 but GUI(active connections) says I have 192.168.1.3:

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
>             inet addr:192.168.0.200  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:10496363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:9349273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:5312676815 (5.3 GB)  TX bytes:781747139 (781.7 MB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:178598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:178598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:41179188 (41.1 MB)  TX bytes:41179188 (41.1 MB)

GUI:
[image]

dhcp eth0.info:

```
IPADDR='192.168.0.200'
NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
NETWORK='192.168.0.0'
BROADCAST='192.168.0.255'
ROUTES=''
GATEWAYS='192.168.0.1'
DNSSERVERS='192.168.0.1'
DHCPSID='192.168.0.1'
LEASEDFROM='1366928965'
LEASETIME='7200'
RENEWALTIME='3600'
REBINDTIME='6300'
INTERFACE='eth0'
CLASSID='dhcpcd 3.2.3'
CLIENTID='ff:65:74:68:30:00:01:00:01:18:ab:f5:fd:d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc'
DHCPCHADDR='d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc'

# dhcpcd-1.x and 2.x compatible variables
DNS='192.168.0.1'
GATEWAY='192.168.0.1'
```

please tell what more is needed if something.
maybe this is related to fact that it tries to use IPv6? I get this idea from syslog:

```
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Withdrawing address record for 192.160.0.200 on eth0.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.160.0.200.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> ((null)): removing resolv.conf from /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dnsmasq[2395]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dbus[876]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> dhclient started with pid 11708
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dbus[876]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: 
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.160.0.200 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.160.0.200 from 192.168.0.1
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost dhclient: bound to 192.160.0.200 -- renewal in 2896 seconds.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   address 192.160.0.200
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   gateway 192.168.0.1
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.0.1'
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.160.0.200.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 26 01:43:58 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Registering new address record for 192.160.0.200 on eth0.IPv4.
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> ((null)): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost dnsmasq[2395]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost dnsmasq[2395]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 26 01:43:59 myhost ntpdate[11793]: no servers can be used, exiting
Apr 26 01:44:00 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc.
Apr 26 01:44:00 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 26 01:44:00 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Registering new address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc on eth0.*.
Apr 26 01:44:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 26 01:44:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 26 01:44:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 26 01:44:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

a fresh additional info:
TP-Link is plugged into LAN port in NetGear (because Internet is in NetGear's WAN) and this is TP-Link's WAN - so correct. Now another issue: I restarted connection, lost it, when I plugged wire of and on again TP-Link listed my Ubuntu with correct IP 192.168.0.200 under DHCP Clients List and in ARP List there is my Ubuntu Mac mapped into this IP so it seems likr TP-Link sees and recognizes my host correctly but host itself says no connection, again: kill dhcpcd eth0 and start it again gives me info that on host IP is configured correctly. However this time I did kill instead of -9 and I have info:

> interface eth0 has been configured with new IP=192.168.0.202

instead of 192.168.0.200
Log info from syslog:

```
Apr 26 13:40:53 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 26 13:40:53 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 26 13:40:53 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 26 13:40:57 myhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Apr 26 13:41:03 myhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Apr 26 13:41:17 myhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <warn> (eth0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 27266
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <warn> Activation (eth0) failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc on eth0.
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc.
Apr 26 13:41:18 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:41:20 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc.
Apr 26 13:41:20 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:41:20 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Registering new address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc on eth0.*.
Apr 26 13:41:21 myhost kernel: [385757.629853] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
Apr 26 13:41:21 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 30)
Apr 26 13:41:21 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [30 20 40]
Apr 26 13:41:21 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
Apr 26 13:41:21 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'.
Apr 26 13:41:21 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Connection 'Wired connection 1' auto-activation failed: (2) Device not managed by NetworkManager or unavailable
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost kernel: [385766.209134] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> dhclient started with pid 27276
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc on eth0.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: 
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.160.0.200 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: DHCPNAK from 192.168.1.1
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> expire
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed expire -> preinit
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.3 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.1
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.1
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.3 -- renewal in 32841 seconds.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> bound
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   address 192.168.1.3
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.1
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info>   domain name 'chello.pl'
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.3.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:41:29 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.3 on eth0.IPv4.
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> ((null)): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost dnsmasq[2395]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost dnsmasq[2395]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost dnsmasq[2395]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost dbus[876]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost dbus[876]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 26 13:41:30 myhost named[12135]: invalid command from 127.0.0.1#46668: bad auth
Apr 26 13:41:31 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc.
Apr 26 13:41:31 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:41:31 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Registering new address record for fe80::d63d:7eff:fe4b:47dc on eth0.*.
Apr 26 13:41:49 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 26 13:41:49 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 26 13:41:49 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 26 13:41:49 myhost NetworkManager[899]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 26 13:42:03 myhost dhcpcd[27383]: eth0: dhcpcd already running on pid 11852 (/var/run/dhcpcd-eth0.pid)
Apr 26 13:42:03 myhost dhcpcd[27383]: eth0: exiting
Apr 26 13:42:11 myhost ntpdate[27364]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Apr 26 13:42:11 myhost ntpdate[27364]: no servers can be used, exiting
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: received SIGTERM, stopping
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: removing default route via 192.168.0.1 metric 0
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: netlink: No such process
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: removing route to 169.254.0.0/16 metric 0
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: removing IP address 192.160.0.200/24
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: netlink: Cannot assign requested address
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd[11852]: eth0: exiting
Apr 26 13:42:45 myhost dhcpcd.sh: interface eth0 has been brought down
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: dhcpcd 3.2.3 starting
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: hardware address = d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: removing IP address 192.168.1.3/24
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.3 on eth0.
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.3.
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: DUID = 00:01:00:01:18:ab:f5:fd:d4:3d:7e:4b:47:dc
Apr 26 13:43:01 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: broadcasting for a lease
Apr 26 13:43:02 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: offered 192.160.0.202 from 192.168.0.1
Apr 26 13:43:02 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: checking 192.160.0.202 is available on attached networks
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: leased 192.160.0.202 for 7200 seconds
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: no renewal time supplied, assuming 3600 seconds
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: no rebind time supplied, assuming 6300 seconds
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: adding IP address 192.160.0.202/24
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1 metric 0
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16 metric 0
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd[27430]: eth0: exiting
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.160.0.202.
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost avahi-daemon[904]: Registering new address record for 192.160.0.202 on eth0.IPv4.
Apr 26 13:43:03 myhost dhcpcd.sh: interface eth0 has been configured with new IP=192.160.0.202
Apr 26 13:53:12 myhost named[26017]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, 192.160.0.202#53
Apr 26 13:53:12 myhost named[26017]: no longer listening on 192.160.0.200#53
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `kill -9` unless a regular `kill` doesn't work.  Second, your description is hard to parse, but it sounds like you have two routers, one plugged into the other.  You shouldn't do that.  My guess is that you have the second router connected to the first on a regular port, rather than the second router's WAN/UPLINK port.  If you do that, you have to disable the routing/NAT/DHCP functions in the second router.  Otherwise, you need to use the WAN/UPLINK port to connect it to the upstream router.

Comment: TP-Link is plugged into LAN port in NetGear (because Internet is in NetGear's WAN) and this is TP-Link's WAN - so correct. Now another issue: I restarted connection, lost it, when I plugged wire of and on again TP-Link listed my Ubuntu with correct IP 192.168.0.200 under DHCP Clients List and in ARP List there is my Ubuntu Mac mapped into this IP so it seems likr TP-Link sees and recognizes my host correctly but host itself says no connection, again: kill dhcpcd eth0 and start it again gives me info that on host IP is configured correctly. However by your advice I did kill instead of -9 ...

Comment: and now IP is configured with "interface eth0 has been configured with new IP=192.168.0.202"

Comment: please see updated log info

Comment: @cf16, double check your connections because it looks like your computer is able to speak directly to both routers and sometimes gets an address from one, and sometimes from the other.  That happens only if they aren't connected using the WAN port.  You might also try unplugging and clearing your leases file, then reboot before plugging back in just to make sure it is starting fresh.